# Migrating from using S-Plus Design package to R RMS package

Tags: r, prediction, splines

I am inheriting some code from S+ that fits a Cox Proportional Hazard model with imputed data. It then uses the Design package to get predicted values and confidence intervals.

```
set.seed(23)

somedata<- data.frame(
  col1 = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE),
  col2 = sample(10000),
  col8 = rnorm(10000, 54, 5 ),
  col22 = rbinom(10000, 1, .5)
)

sd<-datadist(somedata)
options(datadist="sd")

formula1 <- ~ col2 + col1 + col22  + col8
formula2 <- Surv(col2, col1) ~  col22 + rcs(col8, 3)

a <- aregImpute(formula1, data=somedata, n.impute=5)
f <- fit.mult.impute(formula2, cph, a, data=somedata)
p1 <- plot(f, conf.int=T, ref.zero=T, fun=exp, col8=c(18:70), xlab=c("Recipient age"), 
           ylab=c("RR of Mortality"))
write.table(p1$x.xbeta,file=afilename,sep=",",dimnames.write=F)
```

I am now doing this in R. I keep getting an error using the Predict function from the RMS package. Can anyone help?

```
set.seed(23)

somedata<- data.frame(
  col1 = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE),
  col2 = sample(10000),
  col8 = rnorm(10000, 54, 5 ),
  col22 = rbinom(10000, 1, .5)
)

sd<-datadist(somedata)
options(datadist="sd")

formula1 <- ~ col2 + col1 + col22  + col8
formula2 <- Surv(col2, col1) ~  col22 + rcs(col8, 3)

a<-aregImpute(formula1, data=somedata, n.impute=5)
f<-fit.mult.impute( formula2, cph, a, data=somedata)
p2<-Predict(f ,col8,conf.int=0.95 ,ref.zero=TRUE ,fun=exp )
```

on evaluating Predict, the logs shows:

> Error in matxv(adjto, coeff, kint = kint) : 
>     columns in a (4) must be <= length of b (3)

Comment: How should I do this? I don't think I can share my data. I was hoping to get guidance on what might be the cause of the error.

Comment: It's going to be hard for people to tell you how to get around the error if they can't reproduce it. Try reading the linked thread. Maybe you can generate random data that will reproduce the error.

Comment: Hi gung, do you think that will be more helpful? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: (I didn't check, but) if it reproduces your error, it will allow people to be able to help you.

Comment: If you post the smallest self-contained reproducible example that fails I'll debug.  Note that you neglected to have the dependent variable in the imputation, and you don't need to use character strings for formulas; you can just do `formula1 ~ col1 + ....`.  If you follow the documentation for `Predict` and `plot.Predict` it should work.

Comment: Hi @frank-harrell, I hope this example still has some validity to the problem I am seeing in my dataset. It throws the same error. I have updated the code above, also, to what I have been running in R.

Comment: It ran for me.  Let us know the version of rms you are running.  I fixed problems in your code related to formulas and conf.int, but the code ran OK before the fixes except for a meaningless confidence interval.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed a fresh copy of Version: 4.2-1 from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html. I still get the same error.

Comment: Try to remove `ref.zero=TRUE`.  If that fixes the problem, then changes I recently made in `rms`, when posted to CRAN, will benefit you.  If you are running linux I can give you an update now.

Comment: Removing ref.zero = TRUE will allow it to run.  Do you know how long the PC version of the CRAN package will take to post?  I am slightly relieved that I might be using the package correctly.

Comment: I expect that a new version will be on CRAN on about 2015-01-05.  You can check http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms